# How to change vim auto-indent behavior?

Tags: vim, indentation

By default `vim` aligns lines inside LI tags on the same position as the position of LI tag, but I want the contents of LI to have deeper indentation.

Current behaviour:

```
<LI>
first line
second line
```

I want:

```
<UL>
    first line
    second line
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this html plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075).

You can then customize it to your needs. As the plugin page says, you can specify which `html tags` get indented **more**:

```
You can add further tags with 

  :let g:html_indent_inctags = "html,body,head,tbody" 

You can remove tags with 

  :let g:html_indent_autotags = "th,td,tr,tfoot,thead"
```

so in your case simply:

```
:let g:html_indent_inctags = "li,ul";
```